# After upgrade to Sonarqube 6.3 -> upgrade center not working anymore

Tags: web-services, sonarqube, sonarqube-ops

I just upgraded to Sonarqube 6.3 from 6.0. But when I open the update center and try to install the plug-ins I need, only a spinning icon is shown.
After some debug actions I found out that Sonarqube throws following error from within the web-service

```
2017.03.17 10:12:51 DEBUG web[AVrbinF1QOA803FlAAAX]
[o.s.c.u.DefaultHttpDownloader$BaseHttpDownloader$HttpInputSupplier]
Download: https://update.sonarsource.org/update-center.properties (no proxy)

2017.03.17 10:12:57 DEBUG web[AVrbinF1QOA803FlAAAZ][auth.event] 
login failure [cause|Wrong CSFR in request][method|JWT]
[provider|LOCAL|local][IP|xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx|][login|'MY_USERNAME']
```

Normally upgrades to a new Sonarqube version work without problems.
I hope someone got a solution for this problem.

***EDIT***

Apparently the issue lies within FireFox. It works fine with Chrome.... but why?

Comment: I ran into this issue with Firefox (52.0.1), but it worked with Firefox ESR (52.0.1 too)... weird.

Comment: i m getting 401 responses for every administrative action too (even though i am logged in as admin) - on a fresh 6.3 and 6.3.1 installation

Comment: Update: the problem is only with google chrome, firefox 51.0.1 is working just fine